# RequireJS after page refresh Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I recently started to work wit require js, and i have a problem with it.

Every thing is loading up perfect, but some times when i refresh the page i get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

if i refresh again its gone, if i refresh again its there.

Here is my structure

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: siteUrl + "assets/js",

    paths: {
        "jquery": "./libs/jquery",
        "jquery-ui": "libs/jquery-ui",
        "bootstrap": "libs/bootstrap",
        "scripts": "scripts",
        "plugins": "plugins",
    }, 

    shim: {

    'jquery-ui': {
        deps: [ 'jquery' ],
        exports: 'jquery-ui'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: [ 'jquery' ],
        exports: 'bootstrap'
    },

    'plugins/controls': {
        deps: [ 'jquery', 'plugins/dialog2'],
        exports: 'plugins/controls'
    },

    'plugins/form': {
        deps: [ 'jquery'],
        exports: 'plugins/form'
    },

    'plugins/dialog2': {
        deps: [ 'jquery' ],
        exports: 'plugins/dialog2'
    },

     'plugins/chosen': {
        deps: [ 'jquery' ],
        exports: 'plugins/chosen'
    },

     waitSeconds: 25,
}
});

/*
    loading libs for every page
*/
requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'bootstrap', 'plugins/chosen'],
function($, chosen){
/*
    loading global selectors and variables
*/ 
$(function () {
   $('.chzn-select').chosen();  
});

});
```

So i am a really big begiiner with it, could please someone give me a hint, or explain why i am getting this error? And why this happens on page refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surely already a problem:

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'bootstrap', 'plugins/chosen'],
function($, chosen){
...
```

You want to load plugin `chosen`, but in fact it is `jquery-ui`. Since you don't use it, remove the parameter (but not from the array).

I suspect your plugin `plugins/chosen` (among others) has a wrong `shim` exports value.

Did you write those plugins? If that is so, just wrap the code of them in a `define` block and you don't need to shim them anymore:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {...});
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890239/1916258).

Comment: took a deeper look in it, truth is i using requirejs with multi pages, took a look at the export and the other aswer you shown, you where right, i had exports problems, thanks for your help now its okay, thank you again

Comment: can you please elaborate and point out the changes we need to do to make it work ?