# script loading order error - require.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

On the initial load of the app after clearing my cache I get a jquery is undefined bc the app is trying to load jquery validate before jquery has loaded.  After a refresh everything loads in and works fine.  I thought I set this up correctly but am I missing something?  Using backbone.js, require.js and jquery.

Main.js:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    'underscore': 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    'validate': 'jquery.validate-1.11.1.min',
    'templates': '../templates'
  },

shim: {
    jquery: {
    exports: "jquery"
  },
    underscore: {
    exports: '_'
  },
  backbone: {
    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
    exports: "backbone"
  },
    validate: {
    deps: ['jquery'],
    exports: "validate"
  }
},

});

require([
  'app'

], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

App.js

```
define([
  'jquery', 
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'validate',
  'router',
  'scripts'
], function($, _, Backbone, validate, Router, scripts){
var initialize = function(){
  Router.initialize();
};

return { 
  initialize: initialize
};
});
```

**Here is what I have updated the files to, but still no luck:**

```
require.config({
  paths: {
'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
'underscore': 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    'validate': 'jquery.validate-1.11.1.min',
'templates': '../templates'
  },

shim: {
    underscore: {
    exports: '_'
  },
  backbone: {
    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
    exports: "Backbone"
  },
    validate: {
    deps: ['jquery', 'backbone'],
    exports: "validate"
  }
}

});

require([
  'app'
], function(App){
  App.initialize();
});
```

App.js

```
    define([
  'jquery', 
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
     'validate',
    'router',
    'scripts'
], function($, _, Backbone, validate, Router, scripts){
  var initialize = function(){
Router.initialize();
  };

 return { 
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

Comment: I checked firebug html and it looks like the scripts are loading in the correct order - require, main, app, jquery, underscore, backbone, validate but I am still getting the jquery is undefined error on the validate plugin.

Answer (score 1):

jquery validate as seen from here is a plugin which is being called by $.validate().

In such cases, you should not need to do any exporting.

You may try and see if this is helpful for you:

```
   shim: {
        validate: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
```

You can also see a similar stackoverflow question for reference: [How to make a jQuery plugin loadable with requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918063/how-to-make-a-jquery-plugin-loadable-with-requirejs)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the eror? Can you paste a stacktrace?

Also worth checking is the url of jquery. Type your url of jquery (ending on 'libs/jquery/jquery-min') into your browser and see if it can be found.

Answer (score 0):

`exports` must have the same type case expected by third party scripts. In this case: `jQuery` and `Backbone`

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
        'underscore': 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        'backbone': 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        'validate': 'jquery.validate-1.11.1.min',
        'templates': '../templates'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: "jQuery"
        },
            underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        validate: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: "validate"
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, changed the exports and it didn't seem to have any effect

Comment: Did you delete the browser cache?

Comment: Yeah, even double checked firebug that the latest is being loaded in.  Im sure it's something simple I am overlooking.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the start of `validate` source? Maybe you can take a look to the globals there and infer something else from there

Answer (score 0):

The `exports` property needs to match the global property name - in the case of jQuery, it needs to be either `$` or `jQuery`.  For backbone, it needs to be `Backbone`.

You also don't need to be shimming jQuery - it's been AMD compatible for quite a while via a named define.  See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports.js#L15-L17

Comment: Thanks, updated the property names and removed the jquery shim but still no luck

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for the replies, I am sure your feedback fixed some other issues I would have had.  Looks like I was using a really old version of require.js 0.27.0 and upgrading to the latest fixed the jquery issue.